# How to convert lines in txt file to stream of chars / Strings

Tags: java, file, io, java-stream

I need to count lines and words in a txt file, so far i tried with something like that:

```
File file = new File("C:\\output_form.txt");

Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
long lineCount = Files.lines(path).count();

Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path);

long numberOFWords = stream
            .map(line -> line.codePoints())
            .filter(character -> character.findAny().equals("a"))
            .count();
System.out.println("Lines: "+lineCount + "\n" +
        "Words: "+ numberOFWords);
```

I want to:
-convert line of file to stream of chars,
-filter each character that is not a space (i typed .equals("a) to test if it even works),
 
-count it and save it to numberOfWords variable

Output looks like this:

```
Lines: 71
Words: 0
```

Any tips on what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the number of words you should split the lines using spaces `" "` and `flatMap` each word as `String` into a `Stream<String>`.

```
long lineCount = Files.lines(path).count();
long numberOFWords  = Files.lines(path)
            .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(" "))) // this section
            .count();
```

If you further want to filter any specific types of word, you can append a `.filter` after the `flatMap` and before the `count` operation.

In case the intention was to capture all the characters, you could just extend the above solution to `flatMap` lines to their corresponding stream of characters.

```
long numberOfCharacters = Files.lines(path)
        .flatMap(line -> line.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c))
        .filter(c -> !c.equals(' '))
        .count();
```